# How to properly assign a nested DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to assign a DataFrame as a value to a cell in another DataFrame. I've tried it in 3 different ways:

```
import pandas


data = { 'A': [ 1 ] }
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data)

frame['B'] = None

frame.loc[0]['B'] = pandas.DataFrame()
print(frame)

frame.loc[0, 'B'] = pandas.DataFrame()
print(frame)

frame['B'][0] = pandas.DataFrame()
print(frame)
```

First one prints a warning and assigns nothing, second one sets cell value to nan, third one prints a warning and assigns correctly. None of the behaviors make sense to me, the first one because loc is supposed to create a view, the second one because a wild nan appears, the third one because the assignment goes through despite a warning. If I replace DataFrame with a non-pandas object, the assignment goes through in the second case as well, which makes me think it's some kind of special case in pandas. Can someone please explain what's going on here and tell if there is a way to get the assignment through without a warning and without silencing it?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not designed to use lists/DataFrames as objects in the "cells", thus most assignments don't work well with those.

When you use `loc` and a list or DataFrame in the right hand size, pandas tries to interpret the assigned values as something to be expanded to several cells, which fails in your case.

One option is to use `at`:

```
frame.at[0, 'B'] = pandas.DataFrame()
```

Comment: ```at``` worked for some dataframes (constructed via regular constructor) and didn't work for other dataframes (constructed via read_parquet). Or maybe there's another reason.

Comment: @Daniil you probably have a dtype incompatibility. Do you get an error message?

Comment: No, just a nan in the cell.

Comment: Can you provide a constructor for a reproducible example and your pandas version?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that pandas does special case several of these operations. The third one is the most interesting. Pandas warns you about setting data on a copy in the third case - so make that copy explicit. You'll have the overhead of copying B but that is a small cost in the scheme of things

```
import pandas

data = { 'A': [ 1 ] }
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data)
frame['B'] = None

B = frame['B'].copy()
B[0] = pandas.DataFrame()
frame['B'] = B
print(frame)
```

Output

```
   A                                      B
0  1  Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```